# Not convenient TortoiseSVN command line output on MSYS: How to convert backslash to forward slash?

Tags: windows, svn, path, tortoisesvn, backslash

I have a development environment based on MSYS/MinGW.
I use TortoiseSVN command lines to handle an SVN repository.

Unfortunately the TortoiseSVN command lines returns Windows-formated pathes, while Linux ones would be much better.

For example:

```
$ svn st
M       path\to\my\modified\file.txt
```

This is not convenient at all for copy-pasting, and others generic command patterns I used on other OS.

Is there a way to set it up better?
I would prefer to not use aliases.
Or what TortoiseSVN alternative do you use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible solution would be to alias the command by extending ~/.bashrc like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
function svn() {
  command svn "$@" | sed 's/\\/\//g'
}
```